# Firebase database fetching data?

Tags: android, firebase

I am new here in Firebase my question is how to fetch the data from Firebase the below image shows the details of my data base.

I want to fetch the data from `user_time_table` in that Uid is there in each uid there are saven days are displayed in each day there is time and slot are there I want to fetch these tow data in listView and display like in the below image

[image]

[image]

how I have to fetch the time from Firebase ?

```
object class





 public String uid;
    public String username;
    public String address;
    public String day;
    public String slot;
    public long time;
    public int starCount = 0;
    public Map<String, Boolean> stars = new HashMap<>();

    public drPost() {
        // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class)
    }



    public drPost(String uid, String username, String address, String day, String slot, long time) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.username = username;
        this.address = address;
        this.day = day;
        this.slot = slot;
        this.time = time;
    }

    // [START post_to_map]
    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("uid", uid);
        result.put("address", address);
        result.put("day", day);
        result.put("slot", slot);
        result.put("time", time);
        result.put("starCount", starCount);
        result.put("stars", stars);

        return result;
    }
    // [END post_to_map]
    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public String getSlot(){
        return slot;
    }


    public String getDay(){
        return day;
    }



}
```

// [END post_class]

///to fetch and view///

```
enter code here


public class timetable extends Activity {
    ListView listView, listView2;
    List<drPost> drpostList = new ArrayList<>();
    // DatabaseReference databasetimeandslot;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timetable);


         databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user_time_table").child("userID");

        // Get ListView object from xml
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

        drpostList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Defined Array values to show in ListView
        String[] values = new String[]{
                "Monday",
                "Tuesday",
                "Wednesday",
                "Thursday",
                "Friday",
                "Saturday",
                "Sunday"

        };

        // Define a new Adapter
        // First parameter - Context
        // Second parameter - Layout for the row
        // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
        // Forth - the Array of data

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.timetable_items, R.id.type, values);


        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        // ListView Item Click Listener
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {


                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Intent intent = new Intent(timetable.this, EditTimeTable.class);
                intent.putExtra("key", itemValue);
                startActivity(intent);

                // Show Alert
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        });
    }




        @Override
        protected void onStart () {
            super.onStart();


            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    //clearing the previous artist list
                    drpostList.clear();

                    //iterating through all the nodes
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //getting artist
                        drPost drpost = postSnapshot.getValue(drPost.class);
                        //adding artist to the list
                        drpostList.add(drpost);
                    }

                    //creating adapter
                    timeandslot artistAdapter = new timeandslot(timetable.this, drpostList);
                    //attaching adapter to the listview
                    listView2.setAdapter(artistAdapter);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });


        }
    }


enter code here







    public class timeandslot extends ArrayAdapter<drPost> {
        private Activity context;
        List<drPost> drpost;

        public timeandslot(Activity context, List<drPost> drpost) {
            super(context, R.layout.timetable_items, drpost);
            this.context = context;
            this.drpost = drpost;
        }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.timetable_items, null, true);

       // TextView version_TIME = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.version_TIME);
        TextView version_SLOT = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.version_SLOT);
        TextView Day = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.type);

        drPost drposts = drpost.get(position);
     //   version_TIME.setText((int) drposts.getTime());
        version_SLOT.setText(drposts.getSlot());
        Day.setText(drposts.getDay());

        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should probably go through the [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) guide as it covers how to retrieve data from Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().
                child("user_timetable");

databaseReference.child("uid").addChildEventListner(new ChildEventListener() 

    enter code here

{

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) 
                    ObjectModel chat = dataSnapshot.getValue(ObjectModel.class);
            }

            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Replace your object model  class with (Objectmodel) class in onChildAdded method.

Comment: through your model class object.

Comment: there are tow textview below the time and slot but time still not fetching .... and i use the ode add value event listener  not add child event listener...

Comment: one more thing i have change that data base now it will not add the UID so i am getting a major problem now all user data is storing in that 7days only i want each user 7 days of data.....

Comment: Debug your app in and check you get data properly or not from firebase.